# answers not getting passed from question components to quiz component

Tags: angular

I separated my quiz question form into two components, one for **single-answer** and one for **multiple-answer**, and now the answer(s) are not getting passed from the question components to the QuizComponent and also not getting pushed to the answers array.

This seems to be affecting the display of explanation text and scoring is not working.

Please could you see my Stackblitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app** and help to fix this issue. Thank you.

in question.component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>

<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <codelab-question-single-answer [question]="question"></codelab-question-single-answer>
  <codelab-question-multiple-answer [question]="question"></codelab-question-multiple-answer>
</form>
```

in MultipleAnswerComponent and SingleAnswerComponent ts files:

```
@Output() answer = new EventEmitter<number>();
...

setSelected(optionIndex: number): void {
    this.quizStarted = true;
    this.isCorrectAnswerSelected = this.isCorrect(this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].correct, optionIndex);
    this.answer.emit(optionIndex);
...
}
```

in QuizComponent template:

```
<codelab-quiz-question
  [question]="question"
  (answer)="selectedAnswer($event)">
</codelab-quiz-question>
```

and in quiz.component.ts:

```
selectedAnswer(data): void {
  const correctAnswers = this.question.options.filter((options) => options.correct);
  if (correctAnswers.length > 1 && this.answers.indexOf(data) === -1) {
    this.answers.push(data);
  } else {
    this.answers[0] = data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your code, and you aren't capturing `answer` event in question.component.html from codelab-question-single-answer and codelab-question-multiple-answer. You just need capture *answer* output.

```
<!--- question component -->

<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <codelab-question-single-answer (answer)="setSelected($event)" [question]="question"></codelab-question-single-answer>
  <codelab-question-multiple-answer (answer)="setSelected($event)" [question]="question"></codelab-question-multiple-answer>
</form>
```

---

To update corret awnser between question, you need to update "correctMessage" in "ngOnChanges"

```
/**  single-awnser.component.ts and multiple-awnser.component.ts */

function ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.question && changes.question.currentValue !== changes.question.firstChange) {
      /* ...more code here.... */

      /* ADD THIS LINE */
      this.correctMessage = this.quizService.correctMessage;

      if (this.formGroup) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({answer: ''});
        this.alreadyAnswered = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

---

To show the correct answer in *Resultscomponents* you have to check if you already push the question in array, because *ngOnChanges* are pushin many times the same question and answers. To check that, you can create a unique index for each question. I'll use *explanation* to check if you already add the question.

```
 /* quiz.service.ts */

getCorrectAnswers(question: QuizQuestion) {
    if (this.question) {
      const identifiedCorrectAnswers = question.options.filter((option) => option.correct);
      this.numberOfCorrectAnswers = identifiedCorrectAnswers.length;
      this.correctAnswerOptions = identifiedCorrectAnswers.map((option) => question.options.indexOf(option) + 1);
      
      /** add this verification */
      const correctAwserAdded = this.correctAnswers.find(q => q.questionId == question.explanation) != undefined;
      if (correctAwserAdded == false) {
        this.correctAnswersForEachQuestion.push(this.correctAnswerOptions);
        this.correctAnswers.push({
          questionId: this.question.explanation, 
          answers: this.correctAnswersForEachQuestion.sort()
        });
      }

      this.setExplanationTextAndCorrectMessages(this.correctAnswerOptions.sort(), this.question);
      return identifiedCorrectAnswers;
    }
  }
```

**Don't forget to update your ResultsComponent HTML and TS. Because, previously you were pushing an array inside array. Now you are pushing objects inside array.**

Comment: Thank you! Knew I was missing something. I see that explanation is also displaying but doesn't toggle in between questions and scoring works for the first question of DI-Quiz, but doesn't work for the remaining questions... Need to look at the code some more.

Comment: I checked and the explanationText doesn't seem to switch to question text for next question in between questions and correctOptions doesn't seem to display the correct option(s) for next question in the QuizComponent.

Comment: I've added this.answers = []; in my advanceToNextQuestion and it seems to navigate fine now and scoring works fine. I'm still having issue with correctOptions not resetting between questions and displaying the correct options for the next question, and also the correct options for correct answer are not showing up in the ResultsComponent in the accordion.

Comment: You are updating "correctMessage" in "ngOnInit", but this function runs only one time. you have to update "correctMessage"  in **ngDetectChanges**, when the question changes. I'll update my awnser.

Comment: I'll see the ResultsComponent yet

Comment: I found the issue in ResultsComponent. When the question changes you are pushing the same answers many times in correctAnswers  array, because *ngOnChanges* is executted every time that Angular detects changes. To avoid that you can check if you already push the answer in "corretAnswers " array.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the updated getCorrectAnswers() function to the QuizService file, but I'm not sure what I need to add to the ResultsComponent template and TS file to make it work. Right now it only shows the questions in the accordion.

Comment: In the ResultsComponent template you are acessing "correctAnswers" like **correctAnswers[index][0]**. If you are pushing objects you'll have to access like **correctAnswers[index].answers[0]**. E.g: Lines 176, 178

Comment: I'm trying to access correctAnswers as you've shown, but getting an error "Unresolved variable answers," not sure how to define the correctAnswers object in the TS file.

Comment: @mjnyc123, i updated your stackblitz. You're accessing "corretAnswers" correctly, but there were another places do update: In HTML lines: 164, 167, 168, 169. In TS line 112

Comment: I refreshed and I don't see the changes in Stackblitz...

Comment: I don't know why didn't update. Try this link(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-34prtk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainers%2Fresults%2Fresults.component.html). I made some images if the link doesn't work: [Img1](https://ibb.co/6wZ4VXd), [Img2](https://ibb.co/WpQfTb0)

Comment: I added the code locally and it works! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer was helpful, could you vote for it?

Comment: Yes it was very helpful... It says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  Somehow I'm still having an issue with the Unresolved variable answers. Going to try downloading from Stackblitz again...

Comment: if I add correctAnswers: object = {
    questionId: this.quizService.question.explanation,
    answers: this.quizService.correctAnswersForEachQuestion
  }; then the red goes away in IntelliJ, but still get "Unresolved variable answers"